# DFT example in textbook

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

There is an example of the use of the DFT formula in my textbook which I don't quite follow.  The text goes as follows:

Let us define the $N$-periodic and anti-Hermitian series $g_n$ where $g_n = f_n - \delta_n$, so that $g_0 = 0$.  The connection between the alias-coefficients $F_m$ and $G_m$ is here given as $F_m = G_m + 1/N$, where $m = 0,1,..,N-1$.

The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of the series $g_n$ is then

$$G_m = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g_n \exp(-2 \pi inm/N) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} R^n$$,

where

$$R = R(m) = \exp[-i \pi(2m - 1)/N]$$.

It is this last expression here that I don't quite see how it is derived.  What happens, for instance to the $g_n$ term present in the expression $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g_n \exp(-2 \pi inm/N)$?  If anyone can explain to me in detail how this final step is done, I would greatly appreciate it!